# reg query a key value based on another key value

Tags: batch-file

What I'm trying to do is have a batch script return the uninstall link for a program.  So basically I want something like this:

```
Select UninstallString from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall where DisplayName='Sublime Text 1.0"
```

I'm using

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /S^|find " DisplayName"
```

to initially get a list of programs, which then get put in a menu, then I select the program to uninstall and it's supposed to go to that program's registry in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall and get it's UninstallString value

Comment: So what specifically is the problem?

Comment: I have a list of programs and I want to select the UninstallString from the registry that matches a specific DisplayName?  I'm not sure what else you are looking for, I thought I was pretty specific there by give you the exact sql example and asking for the reg query equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "regroot=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
set "file=%~dpn0.txt"

set /a fcount=0
for /f "delims==" %%i in ('set $ 2^>nul') do set "%%i="
if exist "%file%" (
    for /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=|" %%i in ("%file%") do (
        set /a fcount+=1
        set "$d%%j=%%j"
        set "$u%%j=%%i"
    )
    goto:menu
)
echo(building "%file%", please wait
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('reg query "%regroot%"') do (
    set "DN="& set "US="
    for /f "tokens=2*" %%j in ('reg query "%regroot%\%%~ni" /v DisplayName 2^>nul^|find /i "DisplayName"') do set "DN=%%~k"
    for /f "tokens=2*" %%j in ('reg query "%regroot%\%%~ni" /v UninstallString 2^>nul^|find /i "UninstallString"') do set "US=%%~k"
    if not "!DN!"=="" if not "!US!"=="" if not defined $d!DN! (
        >>"%file%" echo(!US!^|!DN!
        set /a fcount+=1
        set "$d!DN!=!DN!"
        set "$u!DN!=!US!"
        <nul set/p"=."
    )
)
echo(
:menu
echo(%fcount% programs with uninstall strings found.
:loop
set /a pcount=0
set "program="
set /p "program=type a program name (q=quit): "
if not defined program goto:loop
if "%program%"=="q" goto:eof
echo(
for /f "tokens=2delims==" %%i in ('set $d ^|findstr !program! 2^>nul') do (
    echo(%%i
    echo(!$u%%i!
    echo(
    set /a pcount+=1
)
if %pcount% equ 0 (echo(!program! not found.) else echo(%pcount% program(s^) found.
goto:loop
```

You can use some of `findstr`'s REGEX capabilities (eg. `/i` for case insensitive search). Please note: to search for all programs starting with "M" you can use `"^$dM"` or `/b $dM`. Searchable strings have always a leading `$d`.

Comment: ok, so how exactly do I select ONLY the program I want.  See where I'm trying to select the reg where the DisplayName is a specific value?

Comment: Just a piece of info that I left out that might be helpful, I'm actually also excluding items from the list when I find the DisplayName, so I can't really do an array of both strings unless the UninstallString is skipped along with DisplayName's that are not used.

Comment: what do you mean with `select program`? The program is the DisplayName! What else? In what kind of information is a progam name hidden? Where can this be found?? What is `program`?

Comment: ok, so when I run reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /S^|find " DisplayName" it returns an array with the name in it, I also have some limiters added on in another find that filters things such as Microsoft and what not.  So I now Have a list of DisplayNames "Programs", I'm trying to query FOR THAT SPECIFIC DisplayName.  SO the reg shows several keys in it, one is DisplayName, one is UninstallString.  So I want to query for the UninstallString where DisplayName contains a specific value.

Comment: OK, I will look into it. :)

Comment: Thanks lol.  Yeah with sql you would just say wherever key=value return all the key/value pairs from that table row.  I just have no idea how to do that here.

Comment: Now you can search for a program, eg. `/i microsoft`  for case insensitive search for "microsoft". `:-)`

Comment: Well, I do that when limiting, the thing is though when I try to do that to only show a specific DisplayName, then return it's UninstallString I get nothing.

Comment: what about this, is it possible to return BOTH DisplayName AND UninstallString in one reg querey?  then I can put both values into an array and call them later while still being able to filter out programs I don't want to display

Comment: Syntax example: `/c:"Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2"`, for help see `findstr /?`.

Comment: yeah, but that only works on returning the Name, it doesn't return the UninstallString

Comment: The script doesn't give any answer, if UninstallString was NOT found! It then says `0 programs with uninstall strings found.`

Comment: well what exactly are you typing in to get both returned?  maybe I'm not putting something in the right place?

Comment: the issue with the above script is that it will return ALL registry values, and if I try to filter them, then I end up with an array of unmatched strings and values.  'set regVar=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
set count=0
set excluded=Microsoft MDOP Dell 
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('Reg Query %regVar% /S^|find " DisplayName" ^| findstr /v "%excluded%"') do (
 set /a count+=1
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 for %%n in (!count!) do (
  endlocal
  set product[%%n]=%%b
  echo  %%n.%tab%%%b
  echo  %%a
 ) 
)'

Comment: ug, I have no idea how to put in code at this point...  it all shows up looking like a run on

Comment: to test, simply type `/i microsoft` in. First line is DisplayName, second UninstallString ( for all Microsoft programs two lines, might be more for long strings).

Comment: nevermind, i aksed if you could put in what you typed in to return a query that gives both, /i microsoft is not a query

Comment: yes, this is a batch query :) batch is not SQL, see `findstr /?` for more help.

Comment: The script now stores the database in a file. I'll make some updates in the next time without more comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this "two-liner":

```
for /f "tokens=7 delims=\" %%a in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /S /F "MySoftware" ^| find "{"') do set ProgramUninstallRegKey=%%a
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3*" %%a in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%ProgramUninstallRegKey% /V "UninstallString"') do set ProgramUninstallString=%%a %%b
```